# RTK positioning vs EGNOS SBAS

Tags: rtkgps+, sbas

With EGNOS sending signals for free and simple GPS receivers with some software are capable of picking up those signals, I assume it is pretty cheap to use SBAS technology. So, why is RTK positioning still around when it requires setting up an expensive base station? Would it not always be easier and cheaper to use GPS receivers with SBAS technology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get details on what you can expect with EGNOS if you contact their helpdesk (https://egnos-user-support.essp-sas.eu/new_egnos_ops/helpdesk), they use to provide quick and useful information for end users! (and as all their services, consulting their helpdesk is free ;))
Best